# Solving for the integrating factor in a Linear Equation with Variable Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am studying Diff Eq and I'm looking through the following example.

Solve the following equation:
$(dy/dt)+2y=3 \rightarrow μ(t)*(dy/dt)+2*μ(t)*y=3*μ(t) \rightarrow (dμ(t)/dt)=2*μ(t) \rightarrow (dμ(t)/dt)/μ(t)=2 \rightarrow 
(d/dt)\ln|μ(t)|=2 \rightarrow \ln|μ(t)|=2*t+C \rightarrow μ(t)=c*e^{2*t} \rightarrow μ(t)=e^{2*t}$

So I have two questions regarding this solved problem. It appears that the absolute value sign is just tossed out of the problem without saying that as a result $c \ge 0$, is this not correct and if not why?

Secondly and more importantly, I was confused by the assumption that $c=1$. Why should it be $1$ and would the answer differ if another number were selected is it just an arbitrary selection that doesn't influence the end result and just cancels out anyways?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I did some formatting using MathJax (see FAQ) as that greatly helps readability, so you can see what it looks like. I also added two solutions to explain why they were able to do that (see answer below). Please let me know if it is all clear. Regards

Comment: did this answer below resolve your questions?

Comment: This was much more than I expected and it was certainly extremely helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: Calculus**

We have: $y' + 2y = 3$.

Lets use calculus to solve this and see why these statements are okay. We have:

$$\displaystyle \frac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{y - \dfrac{3}{2}} = -2$$

Integrating both sides yields:

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{\left(y - \dfrac{3}{2}\right)} = -2 \int dt$$

We get: $\ln\left|y - \dfrac{3}{2}\right| = -2t + c$.

Lets take the exponential of both sides, we get:

$$\left|y - \dfrac{3}{2}\right| = e^{-2t + c} = e^{c}e^{-2t} = c e^{-2t}$$

Do you see what happened to the constant now?

Now, lets use the definition of absolute value and see why it does not matter.

For $y \ge \dfrac{3}{2}$, we have:

$$\left(y - \dfrac{3}{2}\right) = c e^{-2t} \rightarrow y = c e^{-2t} +\dfrac{3}{2}$$

For $y \lt \dfrac{3}{2}$, we have:

$$-\left(y - \dfrac{3}{2}\right) = c e^{-2t} \rightarrow y = -c e^{-2t} + \dfrac{3}{2}$$

However, we know that $c$ is an arbitrary constant, so we can rewrite this as:

$$y = c e^{-2t} + \dfrac{3}{2}$$

We could also leave it as $-c$ if we choose, but it is dangerous to keep those pesky negatives around.

Note: look at this graph of $\left|y - \dfrac{3}{2}\right|$:

[image]

Now, can you use this approach and see why it is identical to the integrating factor (it is exactly the same reasoning)?

For your second question:

You could make $c$ be anything you want. Let it be $y = ke^{-2t} + \dfrac{3}{2}$. Take the derivative and substitute back into ODE and see if you get $3 = 3$ (you do). If they gave you initial conditions, then it would be a specific value, so the authors are being a little sloppy. They should have said something like $y(0) = \dfrac{5}{2}$, which would lead to $c = 1$.

Lets work this statement:

$y = ke^{-2t} + \dfrac{3}{2}$

$y' = -2 k e^{-2t}$

Substituting back into the original DEQ, yields:

$y' + 2y = -2 k e^{-2t} + 2(ke^{-2t} + \dfrac{3}{2}) = 3$, and $3 = 3$.

What if we let $c = 1$, we have:

$y' + 2y = -2 e^{-2t} + 2(e^{-2t} + \dfrac{3}{2}) = 3$, and $3 = 3$.

So, you see that we can let $c$ be anything, unless given an IC.

**Method 2: Integrating Factor**

Here is a step-by-step solution using integrating factor.

- $y' + 2 y = 3$
- $\mu y' + 2 \mu y = 3 \mu$
- $\dfrac{d}{dt}(\mu y) = uy' + u' y$
- Choose $\mu$ so that $\mu' = 2 \mu \rightarrow \mu = e^{2t}$
- We have: $y'+2y = 3$, so:
- $e^{2t}y' + 2e^{2t}y = 3e^{2t}$
- $\dfrac{d}{dt}(e^{2t}y) = 3 e^{2t}$
- $e^{2t} y = \dfrac{3}{2}e^{2t} + c$, thus
- $y(t) = \dfrac{3}{2} + c e^{-2t} = c e^{-2t}+ \dfrac{3}{2}$

Comment: Nice work! When I first saw the question, I thought of you ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Added IF too. Hope the OP gets it! Thx

Comment: @amWhy: I saw all of that and it seems like s/he has an exam coming up and this may be overkill. Sometimes, less is more when they are first learning and I struggle with that - to not give too complex an answer as that likely will serve more to confuse. So, I agree with you!

Comment: @amWhy: Same with me. When I saw the detailed work (+1).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Thank you for the support! Regards

Comment: This is amazingly clear, thank you so much, I did especially appreciate the detail. I am actually self-studying this Diff-Eq and just picked the book I'm using off of the internet "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems" by Boyce and DiPrima. Now I know to use this site for all my questions!

Comment: @Integrandiose: You are very welcome. Happy to help and MSE is a wonderful site with many excellent mathematicians! Although that book has a lot of good things and problems to work, it sometimes skimps on details and is not going to provide the details you are looking for. There are probably other legit and free DEQ boos on the web. You should certainly have a second and maybe a third opinion IMHO. Regards